# Solutions to coupled oscillator.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system of coupled oscillators $$ \frac{d\theta_1}{dt}=2\pi\epsilon\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)$$ $$ \frac{d\theta_2}{dt}=2\pi\epsilon\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)$$

Suppose that at $t=0, \theta_1(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta_2(0)=0$. Sketch the solutions of the solution of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ on the time interval $0\leq t \leq 10$ for $\epsilon=0, \epsilon >0$ but small, and $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: I was told to sketch this by hand, but I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{d\theta_1}{dt}=2\pi\epsilon\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)\\
 \frac{d\theta_2}{dt}=2\pi\epsilon\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)
\end{cases}
\qquad\to\qquad
\frac{d\theta_1}{dt}+\frac{d\theta_2}{dt}=0
$$
$$\theta_1+\theta_2=C$$
 $\theta_1(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta_2(0)=0$ implies $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\theta_1+\theta_2=\frac{\pi}{2}\quad\;\quad \theta_2=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta_1 $$
$$\frac{d\theta_1}{dt}=2\pi\epsilon\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\theta_1)$$
$$\frac{d\theta_1}{dt}=2\pi\epsilon\cos(2\theta_1)$$
I suppose that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so $\frac{d\theta_2}{dt}$ would just be $-2\pi\epsilon\cos(2\theta_1)$ then?

Comment: Yes and $\frac{d\theta_2}{dt}=2\pi\epsilon\cos(2\theta_2)$ . .